# Very slow connection with Airbase-ng

Tags: debian, wireless-access-point, raspberry-pi

I've got a RasberryPi (B+) running Debian Jessie. I'm trying to create my own wireless network which I can scan all the traffic on.

I am using Airbase-ng (1.2 beta3). When I connect my Android phone or Ipad with the created wireless network, the connection is very slow. Speedtests show that my download speed is 0.64 Mbps on the devices. When I run a speedtest on my RaspberryPi (eth0) it sais 44.11 Mbits.

How can my created wlan be so slow?

This is the script I use.

```
cat >/etc/dhcpd.conf <<EOL
authoritative;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        option routers 192.168.1.1;
        option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
        option domain-name "MyWifi";
        option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1;
        range 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.40;
}
EOL

sleep 1

airmon-ng start wlan0

sleep 2

airbase-ng -c 11 -x 500 -e "MyWifi"  mon0
```

Second window (because airbase needs to keep running)

```
DEFAULT_GATEWAY=$(ip route list | sed -n -e "s/^default.*[[:space:]]\([[:digit:]]\+\.[[:digit:]]\+\.[[:digit:]]\+\.[[:digit:]]\+\).*/\1/p")

ifconfig at0 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
ifconfig at0 mtu 1400
route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.1

sleep 1

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -j DNAT --to $DEFAULT_GATEWAY
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface at0 -j ACCEPT
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface eth0 -j MASQUERADE

sleep 1

dhcpd -cf /etc/dhcpd.conf -pf /var/run/dhcpd.pid at0

sleep 1

/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server start
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue using HostAPD instead of AirbaseNG. Adafruit wrote a [very useful tutorial](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point.pdf) on how to setup HostAPD on a RaspberryPi